# transactions in jdbi

Tags: jdbc, transactions, jdbi

I execute sql queries as transactions using jdbi inTransaction() function. I would like to know how/what type of locking mechanism is used internally. additionally, is the whole table locked during the transaction or just the record that has to be updated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The transaction is purely at the database level. It will use the default isolation level for the database/connection unless overridden.

If you are using the inTransaction(...) method which accepts a callback, there is a form of that function which allows for you to set the isolation level:

```
<ReturnType> ReturnType inTransaction(TransactionIsolationLevel level,
                                      TransactionCallback<ReturnType> callback)
```

-Brian

Comment: Am I right in saying that the [official documentation](http://jdbi.org/archive.html) doesn't have a section (nor even an example, nor even a word!) about transactions?

Comment: @leonbly you are correct! There also aren't any code samples in the [transaction javadocs](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/skife/jdbi/v2/tweak/transactions/LocalTransactionHandler.html). And the [transaction annotation docs](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/skife/jdbi/v2/sqlobject/Transaction.html) are even more terse, but the annotation is super easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd part of your question, "...is the whole table locked during the transaction or just the record that has to be updated?", depends on DBMS being used.

Here's, for example, MySQL documentation for table- and row-level locking:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on transaction isolation level. [Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29)